# Algebraic Geometry Dealing With Elliptic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Prove that there exists an infinite set of points,
$$\dots, P_{-1}, P_0, P_1, P_2, P_3, \dots$$

in the plane with the following property:

For any distinct three integers, say $a, b, c$, points $P_a, P_b, P_c$ are collinear if and only if $a + b + c = 2014$.

I first started with shifting the indices of the conditions to $a + b + c = 0$, since dealing with that 2014 is kind of annoying. I then tried to argue that a polynomial of the third degree should exist such that $a + b + c = 0$, where this third degree polynomial hits the $x$-axis at three points, thus satisfying the collinearity criteria.

I honestly have not much experience with this and thus my approach is pretty awful. Help with this would be awesome! :D

Comment: It more or less suffices to find an elliptic curve with a point of infinite order, as the title of your post suggests. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I don't, that material seems very new to me. Could you explain how?